# Drupal: Hide taxonomy tags without images

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

How can I hide from the front end the tags without images?
is there a script that I should add or Can I do it from the backoffice (settings or something)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using views just add filter-> taxonomy_image_field

If it's a custom page you need to write the logic in your custom module...

You need to provide more details if you want correct answer my dude.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am using views, How can I add filter-> taxonomy_image_field ?

Comment: Edit your view, under the FILTER CRITERIA add field taxonomy_image_field and select operator "Is not empty (NOT NULL)" and that is how you will get only terms with images.